Python type hinter function matching Protocol with kwargs
I am having trouble with the PyCharm python type hinter when defining a function that matches a Protocol. It is giving me a warning and I am not sure why.
from typing import Protocol, List, Any

class MyProtocol(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, docs: List[str], **kwargs: Any) -> str:
        pass

def do_call(
    mylist: List[str],
    callback: MyProtocol,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> str:
    return callback(mylist, **kwargs)

def my_func(mylist: List[str], **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    return ",".join(mylist)

# this results in a warning
do_call(["a", "b", "c"], my_func)

The type checker yields the following warning:

Expected type 'MyProtocol', got '(mylist: list[str], kwargs: dict[str, Any]) -> str' instead

Even the example in the python documentation results in the warning on the line that should be ok.
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Protocol

class Combiner(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *vals: bytes, maxlen: int | None = None) -> list[bytes]: ...

def batch_proc(data: Iterable[bytes], cb_results: Combiner) -> bytes:
    for item in data:
        ...

def good_cb(*vals: bytes, maxlen: int | None = None) -> list[bytes]:
    ...
def bad_cb(*vals: bytes, maxitems: int | None) -> list[bytes]:
    ...

batch_proc([], good_cb)  # OK
batch_proc([], bad_cb)   # Error! Argument 2 has incompatible type because of
                         # different name and kind in the callback

For the OK line:

Expected type 'Combiner', got '(vals: tuple[bytes, ...], maxlen: int | None) -> list[bytes]' instead

Is there a way to tell to the type hinter that my function is indeed a "MyProtocol"? Is my implementation correct or is this maybe a defect in the PyCharm built-in type hinter?

You can adjust the code so that the parameter names in the function my_func match the ones defined in MyProtocol. This should silence the warning.

In addition to above you can use a Callable type instead of a Protocol for simpler type checking, and last just suppress the warning if you're confident that the behavior is correct despite the mismatch.
